# Error message showing up in Google search results

Tags: seo, google-search

When I search for a specific keyword in Google. The website shows up, but where normally the meta description is being displayed, it shows a error message instead:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\domains\domain.com\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\canvas\somefile.php on line 417

How is it possible that google shows this line of text instead of a normal description?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's probaly the thing that shows up in either the  or google somehow onlyl got that result when fetching the page.

Google does not filter error messages.

for example if you search **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in** on  you get http://www.bibliotheekgulpen-wittem.nl/index.php/2013-11-04-09-27-41/bibliotheek-wise-ap/134-bibliotheek-wise-app-2014 with a invalid foreach.

Looking at the page itself there is nothing invalid to be seen in the source.

Just bad luck that when google fetched the page it had an error.